# .NET regular expression for reddit style bullets, blockquotes, etc

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, reddit

I'm writing an application that will take user input and convert certain character strings to HTML tags in much the same way that reddit does. I have regular expressions for bold, italics, numbered lists, strikethrough, superscript all working properly, but doing the same for blockquotes and bulleted lists are causing problems.

What I have:
* Text (start of line, asterisk, space then text to the next line break)

```
r = New Regex("(?s)^|\n\*\s(.+?)\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
strOutput = r.Replace(strOutput, "<ul><li>$1</li></ul>")
r = Nothing
```

This appears to be putting bullets in random places.

Likewise, blockquote would be:
> Text (start of line, greater than symbol, space then text to next line break)

```
r = New Regex("(^?|\n?)\>\s(.+?)\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
strOutput = r.Replace(strOutput, "<blockquote>$1</blockquote>")
r = Nothing
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The spec for the features - bold, lists, etc. - that reddit uses for formatting is a variant of Markdown. Is there a specific reason you must use regex to build a Markdown parser from scratch? If not, consider using an existing Markdown libary.

Answer (score 0):

By simplifying your alternations for new line/start of string I was able to get these to work:

```
(^|\n)\*\s(.+?)\n

(^|\n)\>\s(.+?)\n
```

For example, looking for "zero or one start of string" with `^?` doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, especially when alternately matching `\n`.